# How can I wrap BOOST in a separate namespace?

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces

I'm looking to have two versions of BOOST compiled into a project at the same time.  Ideally they should be usable along these lines:

```
boost_1_36_0::boost::shared_ptr<SomeClass> someClass = new SomeClass();
boost_1_35_0::boost::regex expression("[0-9]", boost_1_35_0::boost::regex_constants::basic);
```

Comment: I curious why you would want to do this.

Comment: It was for transitioning to the newer library version while working through some incompatibilities.  Nothing permanent.

Comment: @Eclipse: If you are not exposing any Boost types in your interfaces, you could use the ELF visibility attributes, hiding everything that is not the public interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read (well scanned) through the [development list discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/180008).  There's no easy solution.  To sum up:

1. Wrapping header files in a namespace declaration

   ```
   namespace boost_1_36_0 {
       #include <boost_1_36_0/boost/regex.hpp>
   }
   namespace boost_1_35_0 {
       #include <boost_1_35_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
   }
   ```

   - Requires modifying source files
   - Doesn't allow for both versions to be included in the same translation unit, due to the fact that macros do not respect namespaces.
2. Defining boost before including headers

   ```
   #define boost boost_1_36_0
       #include <boost_1_36_0/boost/regex.hpp>
   #undef boost
   #define boost boost_1_35_0
       #include <boost_1_35_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
   #undef boost
   ```

   - Source files can simply be compiled with `-Dboost=boost_1_36_0`
   - Still doesn't address macro conflicts in a single translation unit.
   - Some internal header file inclusions may be messed up, since this sort of thing does happen.

     ```
     #if defined(SOME_CONDITION)
     #  define HEADER <boost/some/header.hpp>
     #else
     #  define HEADER <boost/some/other/header.hpp>
     #endif
     ```

     But it may be easy enough to work around those cases.
3. Modifying the entire boost library to replace `namespace boost {..}` with `namespace boost_1_36_0 {...}` and then providing a namespace alias.  Replace all `BOOST_XYZ` macros and their uses with `BOOST_1_36_0_XYZ` macros.

   - This would likely work if you were willing to put into the effort.

Comment: If you're going to modify the headers, you might be able to avoid macro conflicts with something like 's/BOOST_/BOOST_1_36_0_/g'. Maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Using [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) can install boost library to a specific location and can replace all 'namespace boost' in their code to a custom alias. Assuming our alias is 'boost_1_36_0' all 'namespace boost' code blocks will start with 'boost_1_36_0'. Something like

```
bcp --namespace=boost_1_36_0 --namespace-alias shared_ptr regex /path/to/install
```

, but check the documentation in the link yourself because I'm not sure if it is legal syntaxis.

Answer (score 1):

@Josh:
While I agree with the shivering, I still believe this is the better course of action. Otherwise, linking troubles are a certainty. I've had the situation before where I had to hack the compiled libraries using `objcopy` to avoid definition conflicts. It was a nightmare for platform interoperability reasons because the name mangling works very differently even in different versions of the same compilers (in my case, GCC).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a world of trouble linking because the mangled names will be different. And yes, I see you knew that, but it seems like it will be trouble all around.

Comment: That would be the point.  I'd wrap all the regex source files in the boostv1 directory with namespace directives too.